# How to Importing csv file into MongoDb (using NodeJS/Express/EJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, csv, ejs

I have in a project the possibility to add several items at once. And I would like to be able to add several items using a csv.

To have more context (the schema) :

```
{
    "_id": {"$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
    "nameCourse": "Name",
    "description": "lorem ipsum",
    "user": [{
        "_id": {"$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
        "name": "John Doe",
        "gender": "M",
        "city": "New York",
        "email": "johndoe@email.com"
    }, 
    {
        "_id": {"$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "gender": "F",
        "city": "Tokyo",
        "email": "janedoe@email.com"
    },
    {
        "_id": {"$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
        "name": "Jake Doe",
        "gender": "M",
        "city": "Paris",
        "email": "jakedoe@email.com"
    }],
}
```

(I'm using NodeJs/ MongoDb (with Mongoose) / Express / EJS )

It has a form with an input:file and a button.

```
<form method="POST" id="add_multiple_user">
               <input type="file" name="user">
               <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
<script>
      $("#add_multiple_user").submit(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      let idcourse = document.getElementById("id_course");

      let unindexed_array = $(this).serializeArray();
      let data = {};

      $.map(unindexed_array, function (n, i) {
        data[n["name"]] = n["value"];
      });

      let addAdresseMultiple = {
        url: `/api/course/add-multiple-user/${idcourse.innerText}`,
        method: "PUT",
        data: data,
      };

      $.ajax(addAdresseMultiple).done(function (response) {
      location.reload();
      });
      });</script>
```

Here my controller :

```
exports.addMultipleUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, gender, city, email } = req.body;

  try {
    await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      {
        $addToSet: {
          user: {
            name: name,
            gender: gender,
            city: city,
            email: email,
          },
        },
      },

      (err, docs) => {
        if (!err) return res.send(docs);
        if (err) return res.status(400).send({ message: err });
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

I saw that there some package (like fast csv) but i didn't understand at all how it can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Koodies for directing me on the right path.

Here's the answer :

in the controller :

```
exports.addMultipleUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
  await csv({delimiter:";"})
  .fromFile(req.file.path)
  .then((jsonObj)=>{
    console.log(jsonObj);
    UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      { $addToSet: { sites: jsonObj } },
      (err, docs) => {
        if (!err) return res.send(docs);
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      }
    );
    fs.unlink(req.file.path, (err) => {if(err){console.log(err); return;}})
   });
    
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

my form & jquery:

```
<form method="POST" id="add_multiple_user" >
   <input type="file" name="user" id="myFileUser">
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
<script>$("#myFileUser").change(function (e) {
  let file = e.target.files[0];
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("myFileUser", file);
  $("#add_multiple_user").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let idcourse = document.getElementById("id_course");
    $.ajax({
      url: `/api/course/add-multiple-user/${idcourse.innerText}`,
      type: "PUT",
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function (res) {
        console.log(res);
      },
      crossDomain: true,
    }).done(function(res) {location.reload()});
  });
  
});</script>
```

Comment: awesome :thumbup:

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to post any answer for you but here is a quick summary of what you might need to breakthrough.

1. Understand [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)
2. Convert [CSV to JSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson)
3. Create multiple items